# How to know when keyboard hides text field?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, keyboard

I have a problem: I can move my view when I click on a text field, but I want my view to move when the keyboard hides the text field. I'm using a table view and the text fields are in different cells. Please someone help me.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean moving your view so your textfield stays visible, when your keyboard pops up and slides over your textfield? In that case, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification as per the tutorial [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-using-a-uitextview.html)

Answer (score 0):

have you registered to receive notifications of UIKeyboadWillShowNotification, and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification.... then your chosen selector can chose wether or not to move the view etc.